# SAP: DATE field on screen but no F4 button

Tags: date, dynpro

I added a date and value field to a screen `(ZFI_ERWEITERUNGEN_KREDITOR, 0100)`. Everything looks fine except the fact that no F4 button appears next to the date field. Checking other date fields the F4 button is available.
Does anyone have a clue where this behviour comes from and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved!

Go to the field attributes in SE51 (Screen Painter):
- Program -> Possible Entries
  Choose one value from the drop-down list.